# C# Printing multiple pages into one queue

Tags: c#, printing

I'm using the following code to generate labels that are printed:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt16(weeks.Value.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
            doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(new PrintReceipt(calendar.SelectionStart.AddDays(i * 7)).DateContent);
            doc.Print();
        }
```

What's happening right now though is that each page is printed as its own page separately in the printer queue. When I have multiple pages sometimes the "cancel" button on the printing prompt in the background gets hit and something can be accidently skipped. How can I put all of the pages above into one "queue" to print at once?

Comment: try move `doc` declaration and `print` method outside of loop?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing multiple times of `doc.Print()`, you should do it only once. To print multiple pages, create a function and assign it to the `PrintDocument`'s `PrintPage` event - let's call it `PrintHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs args)` for example.

Then, in `PrintHandler`, make the current page. Works per page like `args.Graphics.DrawString` are done here. In the end of the `PrintHandler`, set `args.HasMorePages` to `true` if you still have pages to print, `false` if not. If `HasMorePages` is true, `PrintDocument` will call `PrintPage` event again. 1st call for 1st page, 2nd call = 2nd page... so on. **PrintPage() does one page content only, and is meant to be called multiple times.** I think this is a vital concept to grasp when it comes to `PrintDocument`. It's an event called per page.

Hence, you will need to remember which page is the program on currently (e.g. a class-level counter), and tell what content should it print on the page in the `PrintHandler`. Not quite familiar with your `PrintPageEventHandler` constructor here, but if you know the logic behind that, I think you can apply it to the flow described above too.

This is the flow I used in a printer project, not sure if I did it in a stupid way, but it works for me.